# How to use $q's constructor syntax with Angular $http's config.timeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

Since `Promise` is now officially spec-ed and all, how do I convert the `$q.defer()` promise creation in the following snippet to use the `$q(function (resolve, reject) {})` constructor syntax instead?

```js
// Cancel any ongoing $http request so that only the most recent $http
// callback gets invoked
var canceller;
function getThing(id) {
  if (canceller) canceller.resolve();
  canceller = $q.defer();

  return $http.get('/api/things/' + id, {
    timeout: canceller.promise
  });
}
```

(Fyi from [$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage): `timeout` is "… in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.")

Comment: I don't get what your goal is. Your code is fine and working, there's no reason to change anything.

Comment: "*How do I use the promise constructor syntax?*" - [**You don't!**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)

Comment: no goal. just an academic exercise

Comment: Note that the native Promise object does not have a "deferred" api. It seems like `timeout` should be able to accept any then-able object here.

Comment: Oh wait, now I get it. You don't want to convert the `$http.get` call, but the `$q.defer` creation to use the Promise constructor?

Comment: yup! i'll make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
var canceller = null;
function getThing(id) {
  if (canceller) canceller();
  return Promise.resolve($http.get('/api/things/' + id, {
    timeout: new Promise(function(resolve) {
      canceller = resolve;
    })
  }));
}
```

I'll assume you'd never have used `canceller.reject` anyway, so you can just keep around the `resolve` function itself to call it next time.

Comment: $http.get() returns a promise, so I don't think it needs the Promise.resolve() wrap?

Comment: @thatmarvin: It doesn't return one of those shiny new officially specced `Promise`s, but an old boring AngularJs-promise :-) If you want to use Angular promises (and  `$q` instead of `new Promise`) then you can omit it of course.

Comment: gotcha, accepted. very obvious now that i see it, thanks!